# Inter namespace communication over linux bridge

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, network-namespace

So I have the following scenario:
I have a server with 1 physical network interface. On this server I want to create 2 networking namespaces (`NS_NASty` and `NS_MongoDB`). Both namespaces should be able to reach the internet through the physical interface (`ens192`) and `NS_NASty`, as well as the default namespace, should be able to access `NS_MongoDB`.

[image: Namespace configuration]

**Interface config:**

**default**

```
ens192: 172.20.7.57/22
veth0: 192.168.1.1/24
veth2: 192.168.2.1/24
```

**NS_MongoDB**

```
veth1: 192.168.1.2/24
```

**NS_NASty**

```
veth3: 192.168.2.2/24
```

Here is the current config I am using:

```
# create namespaces
ip netns add NS_NASty
ip netns add NS_MongoDB

# create virtual adapter pairs
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
ip link add veth2 type veth peer name veth3

# assign veth peer to namespace
ip link set veth3 netns NS_NASty
ip link set veth1 netns NS_MongoDB

# activate veth peers
ip netns exec NS_NASty ip link set veth3 up
ip netns exec NS_MongoDB ip link set veth1 up

# assign IPs to veth peers
ip netns exec NS_NASty ip addr add 192.168.2.2/24 dev veth3
ip netns exec NS_MongoDB ip addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev veth1

# add veth IPs in default namespace
ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev veth0
ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev veth2

# create ethernet bridge
brctl addbr vbr0
brctl stp vbr0 off
brctl addif vbr0 veth0
brctl addif vbr0 veth2

# activate veth in default namespace
ip link set dev vbr0 up
ip link set veth0 up
ip link set veth2 up

# add default routes
ip netns exec NS_NASty ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
ip netns exec NS_MongoDB ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

I am unable to `ping` any addresses, except for the namespace's respective gateway.

Comment: Have you up'd the loopback interface in each new namespace?

Comment: @TorinCarey why is the loopback interface needed?

Comment: The loopback interface is important since hosts often depend on it, a quick search should give you many reasons why it's important. Pings may not correctly work without it.

Comment: You need to setup IP forwarding between your interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the ip address 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.1.1 with a subnet mask of 24. For the networkspaces to communicate with each other they need to be in the same network block. SO changing the subnet mask to 16 or changing the ip addresses to 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.2.2 might work.